# How to prevent Firefox from starting in safe mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium

Running a Rails test suite with Selenium often opens Firefox with the "Start in Safe Mode?" dialog.   Is there a way to either 1) disable this, or 2) add a script that will answer "No" if the dialog appears?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to some open Firefox issues. Please see here:

[Disable/Change Firefox Safe Mode Hotkey (Shift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111026/disable-change-firefox-safe-mode-hotkey-shift)

If you're looking for an alternative to selenium and Firefox, I've had success with PhantomJS (a headless WebKit browser) and the poltergeist gem.

Answer (score 0):

For **1)Disable this:**

You can create your own custom profile.

For **2)Add a script to answer 'NO'**

Use **Autoit** to write a script for answering NO and use that in your selenium program.