# How to disable safe mode in Firefox 12

Tags: firefox, hotkeys, safe-mode

While I realize this is an older version of Firefox, the system I'm using it on is around 11 years old and it can't take newer versions without the browser and flash content getting sluggish and choppy. This system serves as a public access station and recently I've had someone try to bypass my internet content filters to access material they're not supposed to and they reset Firefox as part of that attempt.

Is truly disabling safe mode possible and if so, how do I **easily** do this?

If not, I've also read from here...

[Disable/Change Firefox Safe Mode Hotkey (Shift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111026/disable-change-firefox-safe-mode-hotkey-shift)

that disabling the safe mode hot key (Shift key) is possible. At the very bottom, there is a environmental variable that can be used to do this: MOZ_DISABLE_SAFE_MODE_KEY=1. How and where do I insert this variable?

Thank you in advance for your time. :-)

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to help, but maybe this will be of use to fellow Googlers.  This blog explains how to disable safe mode in firefox 17, so it may apply to 12 as well:
https://mike.kaply.com/2013/01/11/disabling-safe-mode-in-firefox-17/

If that doesn't help, the regarding the environment variable, that's done from control panel > system > advanced system settings > "advanced" tab > environment variables.  You can put the variable in the upper box if you want it to apply to the current user only, or the lower box if you want it to apply to the whole system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually, it's not too late, I'm still using the computer and copy of Firefox in question. What variable from Mike Kaply's blog do I put in the upper or lower box under "Environment Variables?"