# Disable firefox hotkeys for Selenium test in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, event-handling, salesforce

I need to disable firefox hotkeys in order to test the hotkeys within my Salesforce application.

I have looked up some answers and all I can find for answers are add-ons, however, these add-ons seem to be also overriding the salesforce hotkeys as well (This was tested locally).

I have found other solutions that look as though JS has it solved with an e.preventDefault however I am having trouble finding a similar event handler in C#.

Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: This was voted to be closed due to not knowing what I was asking.  The first sentence is pretty clear what I need.

Comment: See these thread if it help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111026/disable-change-firefox-safe-mode-hotkey-shift